# Transport from airport to downtown Lagos for Benny Hinn and Chris Oyakhilome event

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, transportation, nigeria, los

I'm attending an event in Lagos on October 28th and 29th.

Where can I find information about registered car services with drivers that can take me from the airport to Victoria Island in downtown Lagos?

Roughly how long does this take and what does it cost?

Comment: Sorry, this is was my first time on the forum, so I didn't realize.  Do you have any thoughts on the best way from the airport to downtown?

Comment: "Best" seeks an opinion, and "best" depends on your priorities.  "Best" for a millionaire will be different from "best" for a student backpacker.  If you edit your question to ask more generally about what options exist, and the advantages and disadvantages of each option, your question will fit right in.

Comment: This is my first trip to Nigeria!  I don't really know what the options are.  I assume there are taxis and shuttles and buses and maybe trains, but I know that Nigeria can be unsafe for foreigners, so I was wondering what the safest option was.  I'm neither a millionaire or a backpacker, I work for a non-profit agency abroad; I was hoping to get an answer from someone who has visited Nigeria before or who currently lives there.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to ask how to get from the airport into Lagos, answer(s) would give you the info you need. And for input on hotels, a site such as tripadvisor.com may have useful feedback.

Comment: @pnuts "Easiest and safest" is more specific than "best."  Perhaps that is why the question was better received.

Comment: Hey, due to the comments about me asking multiple questions, I'm going to open up a new thread, if that's okay.  Hopefully this one will be all right!

Comment: @LloydDobbler Better is to press the "edit" button under this one, and fix it. Then, we will reopen i t(it already has 2 votes)

Comment: Sorry, since this one was blocked, I just rephrased my question to make it very specific, and hopefully this time it will meet all the forum guidelines.  Thanks!  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79168/travelling-to-lagos-for-pastor-benny-hinn-and-pastor-chris-oyakhilome-event

Comment: Could you ask your hotel for a private car ?

Comment: Max; thanks very much for the suggestion; unfortunately, my hotel does not offer a private car.  @CMaster -- as far as I can tell, my other question on this topic is closed, and so -- I assume -- invisible, so I have tried to edit this question according to the site guidelines, and to have it purely ask for factual information about car services.  Hope that I did okay this time!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately a visa application I made was rejected leaving me with insufficient time to reapply for a temporary work permit, so I do not have personal experience of the journey but Google Maps has the distance as about 25 km. [A Lagos Airport site](http://lagosairport.preview.server.antiguaairport.net/transport-and-directions/) has:

> Traveling by taxi is also the easiest and the safest way transport in Nigeria.

and:

> Yellow taxis are the most trusted in Murtala Mohammed International Airport but always check driver’s ID, standard rates on the drives tariff card and ask for the price.
>
> Note the distance from Lagos airport to City of Lagos is around 22 kilometers so you should pay around NGN 5000 (32 USD) for 30 – 60 minutes of journey.

Duration to Victoria Island will depend upon the time of day but may exceed one hour.

However, *the easiest and the safest way* is not necessarily easy or safe according to normal standards (eg see [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Travel-g304026-s301/Lagos:Nigeria:Arriving.And.Departing.html)).

Options include a pre-booked [taxi or limousine](https://booking.airportshuttles.com/en-us/#/search?dir=from_airport&mode=one_way&num_passengers=1&currency=USD&start_address=LOS&start_id=&end_address=Victoria%20Island,%20Eti-Osa,%20Lagos,%20Nigeria&end_id=ChIJaYEywC31OxARdqWJNqOhhXg&flight_datetime=10%2F28%2F2016%2012:00%20PM) for ~$38 - ~$216.

It seems that for the Lagos area professional drivers now require [LASDRI](http://www.johnyblogscars.com/2016/05/driving-in-nigeria-and-necessary.html) certification - thank goodness, since driving licences can be obtained with no practical test of learner drivers (!). This is a card with photo, so might be deemed adequate official identification. However, there are many other forms of certification (as mentioned and imaged in the link) eg:

NATIONAL DRIVER LICENCE
NATIONAL CERTIFICATE OF ROAD WORTHINESS
MOTOR VEHICLE INSURANCE
HACKNEY PERMIT

and the author does mention *Haven outlined these documents, having them always in your cars is very ideal* so these may be to hand when seeking to hire a taxi in Lagos.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Is there a good way to check a driver's ID?  Any official info in particular that I should be looking for?